# Reading multiple .txt files into a vector<double>

Tags: c++

Good Day,

I have written the following function that is part of some calculations:

```
vector<double> read(){
    cout << "Add file to calculate, example: name.txt" << endl;
    char file;
    double numz;
    vector<double> myvector;
    char str[256];
    ifstream fin;
    cin.get (str,256);
    fin.open (str);
    while(fin.good()){

            fin>>numz;
            myvector.push_back(numz);

    }
    return myvector;


}
```

This function reads single .txt file with numbers and saves them to vector that is returned for further calculations in another functions.

The function works fine, but I want to edit it to work with multiple .txt files that are saved, an example of this is:

```
Write the names of the .txt files:
data10.txt data20.txt data30.txt
Size of the array is...: 60
```

I have been looking for solution the whole day but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance for any tips and suggestions how to solve this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `istringstream` from the input line and use it to extract file names:

```
//...
cin.get(str, 256);
string str2(str);
istringstream input(str2);
string filename;
while (input >> filename) {
  istream fin(filename.c_str());
  //... process as before
}
```

Comment: For older versions of C++, use `istringstream input(str2.c_str())`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the returning part. If it is so you may consider returning of vector of a pointer to vector.i.e.

```
vector<vector<double>*> read()
```